# MVC 4 object with List of objects not returning list of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a viewmodel that contains a list of another viewmodel.  As demonstrated here:

```
public class PrizeViewModel
{
    public Guid PrizeId { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<CategoryViewModel> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

CategoryViewModel is defined as such:

```
[Serializable]
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

The Prize view looks like this:

```
@model PrizeViewModel

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Prize</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Categories, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default category-create">Create New Category</a>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Categories, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

I then have a CategoryEditorTemplate:

```
@model CategoryViewModel

<div>
    <span><input id="@Model.Id" name="@Model.Id" type="checkbox" checked="@(Model.Selected)" value="@Model.Name" /></span>
    <label for="@Model.Id">@Model.Name</label>
</div>
```

The Create method in the controller takes a PrizeViewModel, problem that I am having is that when I get the PrizeViewModel back, Categories is null.  Any suggestions?

Comment: you have defined editor for list of categories and created editor template for one item. So you have to ways: first loop through categories list and then use EditorFor category item, or instead of this model CategoryViewModel use model IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel> and loop through this model to draw each category

Comment: It does display the editor for each category.  I have also tried looping through the categories in the Prize view with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I don't understand how your Category template is supposed to work.  You're mixing up your Boolean and id and somehow expecting them to bind...  Here's how I think you want it to work.

Change your category editor template to this (it should be called CategoryViewModel.cshtml)  The key is that you need to hidden values in order to post them back to the server.  And, like Stephen mentions, you were overriding the Editor Template automatic collection naming by not using a helper for your input fields.

```
@model CategoryViewModel

<div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Name)
    <Label>@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Selected) @Model.Name</label>
</div>
```

Your prize view should be fine exactly as you posted it.

Do not.  I repeat, do NOT use any form of `foreach` or `for` statement with an editor template and collections.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I knew that I didn't have to use a foreach or for loop for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you loop through categories with **for** **loop** when posting to actionresult it will be able to bind model to list here is post about binding model to list

> http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

here is example of how to make it:

```
    @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Categories.Count(); i++)
    {
         @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Categories[i])
    }
```

Comment: Yea, I just found something like that and tried it, Categories is still coming through as null.  Thanks though, keep the ideas coming.

Comment: sorry I corrected example. Use mvc defined helper to be able to bind categories. if you inspect html code. input name should look something like this -> CategoryViewModel[1].Id or PrizeViewModel.CategoryViewModel[4].Name. This is how it binds model when posting to actionresult check it... in previous example it was writing just values to input attributes and that's why it was null when posting to action

Comment: Nope, still coming through as null.

Answer (score 0):

In your `CategoryEditorTemplate`, you are overriding the default naming required for correct binding when you do `...name="@Model.Id"...`

The html for your categories should look like

```
<input type="text" name=Categories[0].Name ...
<input type="checkbox" name=Categories[0].Selected...
<input type="text" name=Categories[1].Name ...
....
```

Either use helpers in your Template, for example

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Selected)
```

or delete the template and use a `for` loop to generate the html

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Categories.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Categories[i].Name)
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Categories[i].Selected)
}
```